# How do I install phpStorm?

Tags: installation, 11.04

I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

I have installed the JDK.

I have now downloaded phpStorm which was a *tar.gz*.

After extraction I have /bin /lib etc.

I know I can run /bin/phpstorm.sh.

But Where am I meant to put the phpstorm folder?
What permissions do I need to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Intellij IDEA, a similar product on Ubuntu. Basically, you can put it wherever you want. I just made a folder "IDEA" in /home/username. Then I added it to .bashrc (seems silly to add it to path for just that one executable), something like this:

```
alias "idea"="cd /home/username/IDEA/bin; ./idea.sh"
```

Comment: Im going to seem really dumb here, but does adding the alias mean you can do something like `idea myfile.php` to have it open in IDEA?